# how to write this query in laravel query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel

im new in laravel world n didn't know well how to write proper code.
i have a query

> SELECT c.cityname, count(distinct s.namep) as statecount FROM cities c INNER JOIN patiens s on c.id = s.cityidp GROUP BY c.cityname ORDER BY `statecount` DESC;

output query like this

[image]

in my sql database, its work really well with output like i want, but the problem i can't implemented that query in laravel.

in that query i want get how many every city already used by patiens.
thanks a lot for help before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the count, you will probably need to use an element of Raw expression
[Laravel QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)

```php
$result = DB::table('cities c')
             ->join('patiens s','c.id','=','s.cityidp')
             ->select(DB::raw('c.cityname, count(distinct s.namep) as statecount'))
             ->groupBy('c.cityname')
             ->orderBy('statecount','desc')
             ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for the response, that work well with small edited like this in my. "$result = DB::table('cities')
            ->join('patiens', 'cities.id', '=', 'patiens.cityidp')
            ->select(DB::raw('cities.cityname, count(distinct patiens.namep) as statecount'))
            ->groupBy('cities.cityname')
            ->orderBy('statecount', 'desc')
            ->get();"

Comment: To alias table name you may AS keyword.DB::table('cities AS c')->get();   => select * from cities as c

Answer (score 0):

Ideal would be, if you had tables as Models (City, Patien) and Relationships between this two Models.

```
//City model
public function patiens(){
    return $this->hasMany(Patien::class, 'cityidp');
}
```

Than you could just do:

```
$cities = City::withCount('patiens')->get();
```

And in result loop:

```
foreach($cities as $city){
    echo $city->cityname." -> ".$city->patiens_count."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: @AntG already answer my question, thanks a lot and you too